# How to check which fonts are loaded but not used on a website?

Tags: css, web, fonts, frontend, font-face

Ok, so suppose I have downloaded a whole font family with additional CSS file where all styles of a given font are loaded. Like Bold, Thin, etc. But I only use some of those in my CSS, not all.

Is there an easy way to check which ones are not used so that I delete corresponding @font-face declarations and the user won't have to download them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think you can do it automatically I think it can't. But you can search manually in your CSS name of the fonts, if you not see the result (show nothing) in your code you can remove it.

Comment: I know that I could e.g. use grep to look for it manually. I was looking for an easier way...

Answer (score 0):

In Developer tools -> Application,  on left sidebar you can check which fonts was defined in your project. But same like said Habib, you have to check it manually on your own.